# Gathering information in 1 row using related tables

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to build my database using related tables. I am getting the right output from the database, however - Since the user is the same, and the only change in data is the courses, I would like to gather the values "Engelsk" and "Matematik" in the same row, instead of having two outputs which are virtually the same, except the courses. 
Is this even possible without having this in the same row in the database? And if so, I'd very much like to know how :)

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Type] => Elev
        [Username] => test
        [Name] => Test Testsen
        [Grade] => 9. Klasse
        [Course] => Engelsk
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Type] => Elev
        [Username] => test
        [Name] => Test Testsen
        [Grade] => 9. Klasse
        [Course] => Matematik
    )

)
```

So basically what I would like to achieve is something like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
(
    [Type] => Elev
    [Username] => test
    [Name] => Test Testsen
    [Grade] => 9. Klasse
    [Course] => Engelsk, Matematik
)
```

My query looks like this:

```
                SELECT
                *
            FROM
                lek_Essentials
            LEFT JOIN
                lek_Type
            ON
                lek_Essentials.TypeId = lek_Type.TypeId
            LEFT JOIN
                lek_Grades
            ON
                lek_Essentials.GradeId = lek_Grades.GradeId
            LEFT JOIN
                lek_GradeCourses
            ON
                lek_Grades.GradeId = lek_GradeCourses.GradeId
            LEFT JOIN
                lek_Courses
            ON 
                lek_GradeCourses.CourseId = lek_Courses.CourseId
            LEFT JOIN
                lek_Request
            ON
                lek_Courses.CourseId = lek_Request.CourseId
            WHERE
                lek_Essentials.UserId = lek_Request.UserId
```

Comment: If you are using PHP to print the results, as marked in the tags, then you don't need to modify your query, outputing the `$row['Course'],` in a loop, will print them all, separated by a desired sign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly clear what tables each of the columns in your array are coming from but in MySQL you can use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to aggregate the two rows into one:

```
SELECT t.type,
  e.username,
  e.name,
  g.grade,
  group_concat(c.course) course
FROM lek_Essentials e
LEFT JOIN lek_Type t
  ON e.TypeId = t.TypeId
LEFT JOIN lek_Grades g
  ON e.GradeId = g.GradeId
LEFT JOIN lek_GradeCourses gc
  ON g.GradeId = gc.GradeId
LEFT JOIN lek_Courses c
  ON gc.CourseId = c.CourseId
LEFT JOIN lek_Request r
  ON c.CourseId = r.CourseId
WHERE e.UserId = r.UserId
group by t.type, e.username, e.name, g.grade
```